# Displaying a 0 in front of Int

Tags: swift3

In Swift 3, how can I display a '0' (Thats a zero, not an o, as in the number zero) in front of the other numbers in an int. For example, taking the int '3', and making it '03'. Or the int 668899, and making it 0668899.
Thanks

Comment: Check once edited answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly add `0` as prefix to number but you can use `String` to display number with prefix `0`

```
let number = 3
let displayNumber = "0\(number)" //displayNumber is String type
print(displayNumber) //03
```

Now you can use label to display this number.

**Edit:** Thanx @Rob for suggesting about `0` and negative number, so add `0` only when `number > 0`.

```
let number = 3
let displayNumber: String
if number > 0 {
    displayNumber = "0\(number)" 
}
else { //No need to add 0 as prefix
    displayNumber = "\(number)" 
}
```

Comment: This only works with positive numbers. For zero, it would say `00` (which is weird) and for negative numbers, the zero would be in the wrong place.